# c++ Help on stock program

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that has the following criteria:

- You can choose to invest your money in one particular stock or put it in a savings account.
- Your initial capital is 1000 dollars.
- The initial stock price is 100 dollars.
- The interest rate r is 0.5% per month and does not change.

Your stochastic model for the stock price is as follows:

- Next month the price is the same as this month with probability 1/2,
- with probability 1/4 it is 5% lower,
- and with probability 1/4 it is 5% higher.

The principle applies to every new month. There are no transaction costs when you buy or sell stock.

Your investment strategy for the next 5 years is:

- convert all your money to stock when the price drops below 95 dollars,
- and sell all stock and put the money in the bank when the stock price exceeds 110 dollars.

When I try to run the program it gets to the point of buying stocks, and if there are consecutive months where the stock price is below $95 the stocks that were bought disappear. If anyone could help figure this out it would be greatly appreciated.

The code is the following:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    double price = 100;
    double startMoney = 1000;
    double totalMoney = 1000;
    double stockMoney;
    double interest;
    double shares = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
        int prob = rand() % 4;

        if (prob == 0 || prob == 1)
            price = price;
        else if (prob == 2)
            price = price + (price * .05);
        else if (prob == 3)
            price = price - (price * .05);

        if (price >= 95 && shares == 0) {
            interest = startMoney * .05 * i;
            totalMoney += interest;
        }
        else if (price < 95) {
            shares = totalMoney / price;
            totalMoney = totalMoney - (price * shares);
        }
        /*else if(price < 95 && shares >1){
                return shares;

            }*/
        else if (price > 110 && shares > 1) {
            stockMoney = shares * price;
            shares = 0;
            totalMoney += stockMoney;
        }

        cout << "Months: " << i << " Shares: " << shares << " Money: " << totalMoney << " Price: " << price << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `price = price;` I would just eliminate that condition or use a comment.

Comment: Is price an integer or a double?

Comment: What value is `totalMoney` initialised to? It would help to be able to see the entire program. Also, is the loop supposed to exit when this is true: `if (price > 110 && shares > 1)` ?

Comment: `shares = totalMoney / price;` what happens to the shares that are already owned before this statement? If you had any they will be gone..

Comment: You should have had an `if (shares == 0) { } else {}` then handle the price conditions inside these blocks.

Comment: I had issues adding the variables in the original post but i edited them into it now to the best of my ability.

Comment: That is what the {} is for. You copy your code from your ide. Select it and hit the {} button. I fixed your code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks is as simple as this

```
else if (price < 95) {
    shares += totalMoney / price;   // Note the +=
    totalMoney = totalMoney - (price * shares);
}
```

That line is the same as:

```
shares = shares + (totalMoney / price);
```

When stock price is under 95, you will spend all your money in new shares, but you don't lose those you got before and, in fact, you **must** have money to buy those new shares.

With your code, you are overwriting the variable `shares` with 0, because just after buying the *past year* shares you'll end with no money until you sell some shares